# amp-base-carousel breaks out of parent with layout=fill

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am trying to use a flex layout to display one element and allow the remaining element to grow according to the available space.

I am using the following markup and styling to achieve this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AMP Page</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-base-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-base-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
  <style amp-custom>
    .bodywrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: lightseagreen;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    h1 {
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      background-color: green;
    }
    div.wrapper {
      background-color: lightcoral;
      flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    .scrollable {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bodywrapper">

    <h1>Hello AMPHTML World!</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <amp-base-carousel [slide]="selectedSlide" on="slideChange:AMP.setState({selectedSlide:event.index})" id="imageSlides" mixed-length="true" layout="fill">
        <div class="scrollable">
          Exercitation excepteur culpa nostrud consequat consectetur in deserunt.
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable">
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
        </div>
      </amp-base-carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Please ignore that the amp-state is not implemented in this example.)

However the `amp-base-carousel` contents break out of the parent container (".wrapper") and are being displayed behind the `h1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the base carousel, but with AMP's `fill` layout, which requires the container to set `position: relative`.